# Native calls in COM Client / .NET Server Interop

Tags: c#, c++, interop, call, native

I created a C++ pplication that hosts an C# DLL (COM Client -> .NET Server). Now i am able to use the C# DLL classes in my C++ application. My question is now, how can i provide extern functions in the COM Client and use them in the my C# DLL? I want something like this:

1. C++ application starts
2. C++ creates object from C# DLL
3. C++ application calls method from this object
4. C# Method runs
5. C# Method calls native function from C++ application

So i got that working to step 4. I can't figure how i do step 5.

Comment: I used this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2w30w8zx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You should be thinking about callbacks.  An event is the obvious way.  Or more generally declare an interface in your C# project that the C++ code implements and exposes by passing the interface pointer to a C# method.